# Conditional Formatting With Dates And Weekend Special Rules

Tags: excel-formula

I need to highlight cells based on the date in column AG. I am using conditional formatting but can't seem to get the formula right.

Logic:

- If Today() is a Monday I need to highlight the cell if the date in AG is the PREVIOUS Friday, Saturday and Sunday
- If Today() is a Tuesday through Friday then I need to highlight if the date in AG is the previous day

I started the formula like this but it is not working properly:

```
=OR(TODAY()=WEEKDAY(3),WEEKDAY(4),WEEKDAY(5),WEEKDAY(6),AG10=TODAY()-1,OR(IF(TODAY()=WEEKDAY(2),AG10<TODAY()-4)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
=OR(AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())>= 3,WEEKDAY(TODAY())<=6,INT(AG10)=INT(TODAY()-1)),AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=2,INT(AG10)>=INT(TODAY()-3),INT(AG10)<=INT(TODAY()-1)))
```

Comment: Scott, this formula doesn't work for conditional formatting. The message I am getting is that "You may not use reference operators(such as unions, intersections, and ranges) or array constants for conditional formatting criteria"

Comment: @MEC see edit.  I tried some shorthand that works in the sheet, forgetting that conditional formatting does not allow it.

Comment: I used this formula and I think it will work but have to wait until Monday to truly test it out: =OR(AND(OR(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=3,WEEKDAY(TODAY())=4,WEEKDAY(TODAY())=5,WEEKDAY(TODAY())=6),INT(AG10)=INT(TODAY()-1)),AND(WEEKDAY(TODAY())=2,INT(AG10)>=INT(TODAY()-3),INT(AG10)<=INT(TODAY()-1))).  Do you think it will work the way I separated the weekday() functions?

Comment: @MEC see my latest edit, we can set the extents and skip the middle days.

Comment: Scott this seems to work but I won't know until this Monday to test the main part which is the weekend. However, I do have a need to count the amount of new loans using this logic, can I incorporate countifs with your formula? I think it would be your original formula not the modified one, can you post it for me? I tried this formula but it gave me zero when it should have been 2 based on my data and your conditional formatting formula: =COUNTIF($AG$10:$AG$500,OR(TODAY()=WEEKDAY(3),WEEKDAY(4),WEEKDAY(5),WEEKDAY(6),AG10=TODAY()-1,OR(IF(TODAY()=WEEKDAY(2),AG10<TODAY()-4)))).